# ubuntu 18.04 vps: auth.log, postfix and webmin users

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, vps

I have a VPS with ubuntu.

1.I don't need postfix so I shut it down. Today I saw it is up again. how can I stop it completely? does a `sudo service postfix stop` enough?
What about dovecot? Do I need it or can I stop it as well?

2.I have 40+ users in usermin. I only use root but maybe other processes use other users? How can I know which user I can remove? Or if it's not me who created it, I can delete it?

3.auth.log and mail.log were too big so I deleted them and they were not recreated. I created auth.log and `sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log/auth.log` but it is still empty. What should I do so those files will be created with logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be really making a separate post for each of your questions, otherwise this will be to broad.  You also should provide more detail regarding the VPS; did you install it yourself? Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

As an answer to 1)
Since 16.04 the canonical (haha) way of disabling services is typically using systemd, so `systemctl disable <service-name>` ...

Ad 2) if it's your server, and you're looking after it, you should know what users you have and whether they need to be there.  Are you talking about system accounts (users with IDs smaller than 1000) that are running certain processes? Are they regular user accounts?

Ad 3) Try restarting (r)syslog.

Comment: 1. subject updated. I used your tip. I hope it will be for good. What about dovecot? 2. I didn't create them. ROOT is 0, I have others from 1 to 10 and so on, I have tomcat 999 ftp 115 etc. I don't know if they are doing anything, for now I disabled them, not sure if it's enough. 3. auth.log is now working, thanks. mail.log is missing but I disabled postfix so it is expected, right?

Comment: I do see "Successful su for <user> by root" "session opened for user <user> by (uid=0)" "New session c448 of user <user>" "session closed for user <user> session closed for user root"

Comment: Well ... you could check for the presence of system-users in the output of `ps -ef` ... if they feature there they're most likely running a daemon. If their UID is below 1000 (e.g. your tomcat or ftp) they're system-users, but may not be active (or only become "active" via cron-jobs).  But teaching you Linux basics here is really inappropriate .. and yes, if postfix is turned off I wouldn't expect any logging.  As for the size, contemplate enabling logrotation ...

Comment: Thanks, 1. do I need dovecot?  2. the <user> above does appear with /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2 and user opendkim appears with /usr/sbin/opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid -p inet:8891@127.0... how can I know it's not bots or hacks? No need to teach me linux and I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: if you have both packages installed it's most likely legit; but we can't know what decisions you made.

Comment: I'll ask it generally then: how can I know/check which user is legit and which is not? For example: I have a user tomcat, I do have tomcat = legit. next.

Comment: Well ... as I said: for each **<USERNAME>** in question you could do this: `grep -RlE '(adduser|useradd).*<USERNAME>^C/var/lib/dpkg/info --include='*inst' | sed -r 's:.*/(.*)\.[-a-z]+inst:\1:'`  .... but this *really* isn't the place to teach you Linux.